# keep getting http bad request on rest api

Tags: rest, artifactory

I can't create a user in Artifactory via REST API.

Doc I'm using: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateorReplaceUser

my rest call:

```
curl -k -u user:pass -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" "$API_URL/security/user/$USERNAME" -t $BUILD_ID.json
```

content of $BUILD_ID.json:

```
{"name" : "test","password" : "password","groups" : ["test","Test_AJU_group"]}
```

but unfortunately still getting http error 400 - bad request.

> 14:57:12 {
>   14:57:12   "errors" : [ {
>   14:57:12     "status" : 400,
>   14:57:12     "message" : "Bad Request"
>   14:57:12   } ]
>   14:57:12 }Finished: SUCCESS

I tried to send data in URL instead of file with same results.

Comment: after Jason's help, same command just repaired typo, i'm getting: 

09:44:45     "message" : "No content to map to Object due to end of input"

as i understand it, client do not end http connection after data send. Can someone help me to solve this one, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `/security/user` => `/security/users`?

Comment: thanks, atleast someone can read while me can't. This one helped me! :)